# Trying to reduce edge count in Edit Mode

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, edges, .fbx

Someone gave me an fbx model with too many edges throughout it and I'm looking to reduce that quantity without destroying the overall mesh.
If I delete edges individually the faces delete as well. And even if that didn't happen, it would easily turn into a multi-hour job before I was even halfway.
I know in Autodesk Maya (2014 version) there was a feature that could reduce/increase the amount of mesh with the click of a button. Might have even been a shortcut.
Everyone says to use the Decimate Modifier but this has no effect on the mesh in Edit Mode.

Does this feature exist in Blender? Is it because of the fbx file type? Is the Decimate just not working?

What's wrong here?

Comment: Try X > Limited Dissolve, adjusting the threshold angle.

Comment: The effects of the Decimate Modifier cannot be seen in edit mode. I recommend viewing it through Object Mode > Wireframe Preview, so you can see how it's editing the geometry. You will also not see any changes until you adjust the value(s) in any of the respective categories (Collapse/Un-Subdivide/Planar).